# GDI: How to fill RoundRect with color?

Tags: visual-c++, gdi

While the question title seems dumb, that's not exactly what I need. To fill **whole** area with color, one needs to select appropriate brush - that's trivial. But I want to fill upper half of it with different color, and bottom half of it with the different one. If it was the normal (not round) rectangle, I could draw two rectangles (with different brushes). But with RoundRect I don't have any ideas how to do it.

*Here is what I need it for: I draw each node in my graph visualization with RoundRect, and those nodes should have several compartments (cells) that should be filled with different colors.*

I hope you get the idea what I mean :)

Comment: Use clipping.  IntersectClipRect() would work.  Or use Paths, FillPath would work.

Comment: I'd say clipping would be the easiest thing. Divide the area in half and set a clip rectangle in your `WM_PAINT` handler. Not sure why Hans didn't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to use legacy GDI instead of GDI+, here I wrote you a function to draw such a (cell) as you needed I hope it is what you have expected !

The basic idea is to create upper and lower regions (which they were both full overlapping rounded rectangles, then each has one of its halves cut off)

[image: Diff operation to show how to created the upper have of the intended "cell"]

I have prepared the above illustration to show how the cell could be produced. It's for the upper side only, but you should have got the idea of creating the lower one.

Here is a wrapping function to create the cell you need:

```
   void DrawCell(HDC& hdc, const RECT& rcTarget,const HBRUSH& hbrUpper, const HBRUSH& hbrLower)
    {

        HRGN hRgnUpper = CreateRoundRectRgn(rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top, rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom, 42, 38);      
        HRGN hRgnLower = CreateRoundRectRgn(rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top, rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom, 42, 38);

        HRGN hRgnCutFromUpper = CreateRectRgn(rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top + ((rcTarget.bottom - rcTarget.top) / 2), rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom);       
        HRGN hRgnCutFromLower = CreateRectRgn(rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top , rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom - ((rcTarget.bottom - rcTarget.top) / 2));      

        CombineRgn(hRgnUpper, hRgnUpper,hRgnCutFromUpper, RGN_DIFF);
        CombineRgn(hRgnLower, hRgnLower,hRgnCutFromLower, RGN_DIFF);


        FillRgn( hdc, hRgnUpper, hbrUpper);      
        FillRgn( hdc, hRgnLower, hbrLower);  

        DeleteObject(hRgnCutFromLower);
        DeleteObject(hRgnCutFromUpper);
        DeleteObject(hRgnLower);
        DeleteObject(hRgnUpper);



    }
```

call this function from within your WM_PAINT handler:

```
        RECT rcTarget;
    rcTarget.left = 20;
    rcTarget.top = 20;
    rcTarget.right = 275;
    rcTarget.bottom = 188;

    HBRUSH hRed = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255, 0, 0) );  
    HBRUSH hGreen = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(0, 255, 0) );  

    DrawCell(hdc, rcTarget, hRed, hGreen);
```